# why is FormData erroring

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, forms

I am trying to upload an image using ajax and FormData

my html looks like:

```
<form id="profile-photo-form">
    <input type="file" id="profile-photo-choose" name="photo_path" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

and js function called on change of the file selector:

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#profile-photo-form')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: api_url,
    data:form_data,
    headers:{
        'X-CVL-Auth': cookie
    },
    success: function(result){
```

but I get a javascript error of:

```
TypeError: Can only call DOMFormData.append on instances of DOMFormData
```

this is for a html app loaded on ios (phonegap)

Comment: Just use `data: $('#profile-photo-form').serialize()`. You do not need to use `FormData` as `serialize` does all the work for you.

Comment: The error refers to a call to `.append` on a formdata object but your code does not show that.

Answer (score 8):

Other comments pointed out that you can just use `.serialize()`, however, this won't work on any field that contains an image.

Using this same method, simple add another setting `processData: false` to stop the JS from trying to look at your data, and instead just submit everything it gets back as a hash.

I haven't tested every case, but this SHOULD submit the data in the exact same format as if you had submitted without AJAX.

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#profile-photo-form')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: api_url,
    data:form_data,
    processData: false, // add this here
    headers:{
        'X-CVL-Auth': cookie
    },
    success: function(result){
```

Comment: I also had to add `contentType: false` for it to work.